# Using hamcrest to assert that I get a collection of Objects back and that one of them has a property set to a particular value?

Tags: java, junit, assert, hamcrest

I just started using Hamcrest, so I'm probably doing it all wrong.

I have a `List<Foo> foos` and the `Foo` interface looks a bit like this:

```
public abstract interface Foo {

  public String getBar();

}
```

It is implemented by `impl.FooImpl`:

```
public class FooImpl implements Foo {

  protected String _bar = "some value";

  public String getBar() {
    return _bar;
  }

}
```

My assert looks like this:

```
assertThat(
  foos, 
  Matchers.hasItem(
    Matchers.<Foo> hasProperty(
      "bar", 
      equalTo("some value")
    )
  )
);
```

Unfortunately, JUnit/Hamcrest isn't happy:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("bar", "someValue")
     got: <[com.example.impl.FooImpl@2c78bc3b]>
```

Any idea what I need to do to fix this?

**Update:** My "test" class is here:

```
public class FooTest {
  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
    List<Foo> foos = Arrays.<Foo> asList(new FooImpl());
      assertThat(
        foos, 
        Matchers.<FooImpl> hasItem(Matchers.hasProperty("bar", equalTo("some value")))
      );
  }
}
```

Clearly, what I'd like to see is that assert pass without getting an exception... :)

**Update**: this is now fixed; I just set up a blank maven project in IntelliJ and it ran fine. It might have been down to a typo, or me importing the wrong method in Eclipse, but it's a OSI Layer 8 problem for sure. I asked for the conversation to be closed. Sorry everyone, and thanks for your help.

Comment: The name of your property is "bar", not "_bar". "_bar" is the name of your private field. The name of a property is what follows `get` in the getter.

Comment: Why the vote to close? If this isn't what SO is for then I don't know what is

Comment: I now cross-posted this to the hamcrest user group at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/hamcrest-java/AmZGLq0Kby0/ojd9XbbxjGUJ as someone apparently thinks it doesn't belong here...

Comment: @Christian Currently you have one close vote, which says that questions "*must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself*". You may continue to get such close-votes if you don't provide a compilable example of your problem. Nothing speeds up the arrival of an answer quite like a reproducible problem.

Comment: Could you please use the assertThat of Hamcrest 1.3. It prints more details about why it failed.

Comment: @stefan-birkner Hamcrest 1.3 seems to return a very similar error message in my case... :/ But I just figured out what the problem was anyway...

Comment: For the sake of completeness: This won't work on Android as the `hasProperty` part will throw `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/beans/Introspector;`. This seems to be caused by the fact that google did not package the complete JDK into Android SDK. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36966516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted works fine. The error you have is due to a mismatch between `"someValue"` and `"some value"` in the code you're running locally. Upgrade to Hamcrest 1.3 and you'll get a clearer error message:

```
Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("bar", "someValue")
    but: property 'bar' was 'some value'
```

Since you may be getting different results, here's a full example that passes, with JUnit 4.11 and Hamcrest 1.3. In `Foo.java`:

```
public class Foo {
    public String getBar() {
        return "some value";
    }
}
```

And in `FooTest.java`:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(new Foo());

        assertThat(foos,
                Matchers.<Foo>hasItem(Matchers.hasProperty("bar", Matchers.equalTo("some value"))));
    }
}
```

If I intentionally break this test by changing the property name in the test to `"notbar"` then I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("notbar", "some value")
     but: No property "notbar"
```

If, instead, I break it by expecting `"some other value"`, then I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("bar", "some other value")
     but: property 'bar' was "some value"
```

If you're getting different, or less clear, errors, you may have a separate issue.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I just created a blank maven project in IntelliJ and used my code form above, and it works fine. I'll have to check what the issue really is in Eclipse, whether it's using a bad import or an actual typo, but it's probably something minor. Thanks for spotting this. :)

Comment: So, my property is called `_FooBar`, the getter is called `getFooBar()`, and the right matcher is `Matchers.equalTo( "fooBar", "some value")`... ***(Note the LOWERCASE "f".)*** Also, the error messages of hamcrest 1.3 for this weren't any better after all... :)

Comment: My getter and setter were not public and mockito made me bang my head for 2/3 hours... making getter public for property being used in testcase solved the issue